# Trigonometric problem regarding a tower

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

The angle of elevation of a tower, $CD$, from a point $A$ due East of the tower is 45°. From a point $B$ due south of $A$, the angle of elevation is 30°. The distance from $A$ and $B$ is 400 metres. Find the height, $h$, of the tower. Write your answer correct to three significant figures.

Thank you for any help!
[image: Image to help visualise]

Comment: So put $AC=x$. What does that give you for $h$ using the 45 deg elevation? And the 30 deg elevation?

Comment: what confuses me is this. you say that $A$ is to the east and $B$ is to the south. This means that $\angle ACB$ is $90^o$. Then how do you show $\angle BAC$ to be $90^o$? Or is that a printing mistake?

Comment: B is south of A

Comment: Why not show  your work, when you understood this part correctly? CA, CB are unknown but connected by Pythagorean relation. How do you link them with $h?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You have $CA=h$ and $CB=h\sqrt{3}$ and $CB^2=CA^2+AB^2$ so the equation:

$$
3h^2=h^2+(400)^2
$$

Comment: I don't think this is correct, it is the right thinking but shouldn't it be $$CB=\frac{h}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: we have $h=CB \tan 30°$ so $h=CB/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Yes but once you simplify to get $CB$ in terms of $h$, you would find $CB=\frac{h}{\sqrt3}$ Thus meaning the final equation would look something like: $$(\frac{h}{\sqrt3})^2=h^2+400^2$$

Comment: If $h=CB/\sqrt{3}$ than $CB=h \sqrt{3}$....

Comment: Right sorry my bad, I didn't see your fraction line and also forgot that tan(30) is 1/sqrt(3) Thanks for your help :)